# Why might include_once fail to register a class in a zend cli script but not app

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework 1 application with a web module and a cli module.

index.php is in the web root /crm/app/www, of course, and there is an almost identical run.php in /crm/app/cli  most importantly, I think, they both load the same application.ini from /crm/app/configs/application.ini

The application.ini includes a line for

timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"

The actual failure is in an autoload, but I can simply like this:

I put 
                    include_once('C:\wamp\www\client22\crm\lib\Crm\DateTime.php');
                    $res = get_declared_classes();

in /crm/app/www/controllers/DashboardController::indexAction()

and stepwise debug to the $res.... I see Crm_DateTime in the declared classes array

I put
                    include_once('C:\wamp\www\client22\crm\lib\Crm\DateTime.php');
                    $res = get_declared_classes();

in crm/app/cli/controllers/AutomationController::processAction()
and stepwise debug to the $res line.... no Crm_DateTime

I have Crm_Email and Crm_Logger which I can add in the same place and have them show as being declared in the cli module....

C:\wamp\www\client22\crm\lib\Crm\DateTime.php is pretty basic

`class Crm_DateTime extends DateTime
{`

```
     /**
 * When false, the date had a parse error
 * @var bool
 */
public $isValid = true;

/**
 * A reference to the DateTimeZone object that belongs to this object
 * @var DateTimeZone
 */
protected $_timezone;
protected $_timezonestring = "America/Los_Angeles";


    //.... a few more protected properties such as an array of holidays
    //...  a few simple methods to do client specific validation
```

}

I can post more as necessary... but the problem is not in what the class does... the problem is that it simply does not get 'declared' or 'registered' or whatever include_once should actually do with a class.... As I step through the code... I even see that the file is found and 'included' -- at least the include_once call causes it to show up on screen before stepping to $res = get_declared_classes();

What this means in the long run is that in the actual use of the class... the Zend autoloader does the include_once and then

`if (!class_exists($class, false) && !interface_exists($class, false)) {`

require_once 'Zend/Exception.php';

throw new Zend_Exception("File \"$file\" does not exist or class \"$class\" was not found in the file");

```
    }
```

and that is where the exception gets thrown and my cli app dies..... grrrrr

I have exhausted my imagination. Where would you look to diagnose the failure of this class to get registered?

Thanks tons,

G

Comment: Update #1 -- the call to include_once is actually causing the php file to be echoed to console

Comment: Update #2 The class file started with a short open tag <?   and even though short_open_tag was enabled in php.ini  this did not seem to be working for this particular instance... I changed <? to <?php  and problem solved....